# How do I localize images in my ASP.NET site outside of visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, localization, embedded-resource, resx, al.exe

I have a culture neutral resources.resx file which contains text strings and images. This compiles into "controls.web.dll".

The requirement is that I generate satellite assemblies (eg. \fr\controls.web.resources.dll for french) post code-freeze which contains all the translated text and images and this is where I'm stuck.

We have +-115 .resx files. I've used the **Crowdin.com** tool to translate the text strings and I've used **resgen** to convert the translated .resx files to .resources which I compile into satellite assemblies using **al.exe**. All this is done outside of visual studio and can be scripted/automated on our build server.

My problems is that this process works fine with the text strings as they're simply replaced by the translator. The problem is the translated .resx still has references the neutral image.

```
  <assembly alias="System.Windows.Forms" name="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
  <data name="_46pxNoImage" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\AttachmentPostBack\Resources\46pxNoImage.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
```

Do I have to manually edit all 115 .resx (XML) post translation and change all image references to point at each respective translated image (eg. **\AttachmentPostBack\Resources\46pxNoImage.fr.png**) OR is there a better, less painful way to do this? Microsoft is really lacking on the documentation so I'm wondering if this is even the best method/practice for localizing images in ASP.net